# How can I read in a service status and pass it on to Slack via JSON in bash

Tags: json, bash, shell, slack-api

I have this script currently...

```
#!/bin/bash
# Check NGINX
nginxstat=$(service nginx status)

# Checking Sites
hostsite="localhost:81 - "$(curl --silent --head --location --output /dev/null --write-out '%{http_code}'  http://localhost:81 | grep '^2')

##########
# Send to Slack
curl -X POST --data '{"channel":"#achannel","username":"Ansible", "attachments": [{"fallback":"NGINX Reload","pretext":"'"$HOSTNAME"'","color":"good","fields":[{"title":"nginx localhost","value":"'"$hostsite"'","short":true},{"title":"NGINX","value":"'"$nginxstat"'","short":true}]}]}' -i https://xxx.slack.com/services/hooks/incoming-webhook?token=xxx
```

I've tried and tried and failed; I want to grab the result of a nginx configtest and push it in. At the moment an nginx reload kicks in prior to this being ran, the reload does a configcheck itself so the server stays up if the config is wrong. 
So my nginx status command (which works) displays

```
NGINX
----------------
nginx (pid  1234) is running...
```

but I can't get the same to work with config test, which i expect is due to the nature of the escaping required and the other junk it pumps out ala

```
nginx: [warn] "ssl_stapling" ignored, issuer certificate not found
nginx: the configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf syntax is ok
nginx: configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf test is successful
```

Comment: consider editing your question to include the 'config test' command line that isn't working. It's probably a quoting problem. I would look into redirecting any output that you want to send into a file, then use the `@/path/to/file_to_send` syntax from `curl` to send it, rather than try embed results into the cmd-line.

Comment: @shellter I was using nginxtest=$(service nginx configtest)
but as config test returns multiple rows of messages and contains " it goes to pot

Comment: can't you pipe that output to `sed` and just take the lines your want? i.e. `nginxstatCfg=$(service nginx configtest | sed -n '/stuff I want/p')` ? (again, if we could see the problematic output, we can give a more specific answer ;-) ). Good luck.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Transform your variable into a JSON string with [jq](http://stedolan.github.io/jq/) before you embed it in the POST data:

```
$ echo '"some quoted stuff"' | jq @json
"\"some quoted stuff\""
```

For example:

```
nginxstat=$(service nginx status | jq @json)
```

Then embed unquoted. See also the [manual](http://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/#Builtinoperatorsandfunctions).

Or, if you want it JSON escaped then bash escaped:

```
echo '"some quoted stuff"' | jq "@json | @sh"
"'\"some quoted stuff\"'"
```

Did I mention that [jq](http://stedolan.github.io/jq/) is my new favorite thing?

http://stedolan.github.io/jq/

Comment: Nice; never seen it before :)

Comment: I didn't know about `jq` until a few months ago, and I was like "Where has this been all my life?" It's like `xpath` for JSON and so much more.